# How to add a image to a Microsoft teams tab title

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am creating a app for Microsoft Teams. I am trying to create a tab using microsoft graph post api.

`/teams/${teamId}/channels/${channelId}/tabs` payload is an object with following params:

```
{
   displayName: 'My Tab'
   'teamsApp@odata.bind': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web',
   configuration: {…},
};
```

Currently creating Tab with tab name 'My Tab'. How can I prepend a image along with name. e.g. '+image+ My Tab'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to add image with displayName in Teams Tab.
**This is by design**.

Ref Doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-tabs?view=graph-rest-1.0

Could you please raise an user voice here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)